# Running Query from Jenkins on Oracle Database

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am very new to jenkins so please help me.

I have a server where Jenkins is installed. I do not have access to that server. I have a remote Oracle Database. I want to run a query on remote oracle database from jenkins. i am using SQLScript Runner Plugin for Jenkins. But while building the project i am getting an error Oracle Home Not found.
Do i have to give path of oracle home from my system or the system where Jenkins is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the ORACLE_HOME environment variable in your Jenkins Host or in the Jenkins Environment Variables.

A workaround is to use the [SQLPLUS Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html) (link for windows) you can select "Run a Windows Command" option and in the box you can put the command

```
sqplus user/password@host:port/SID @path/of/your/script.sql
```

Comment: I can not install any software on the server. Oracle client is not installed. Can i install Oracle Instant client with Docker? If yes Can you please share how?